# udp on an osx machine with R15B03

Tags: erlang

i try to multicast over udp, but i run in problems when i use erlang R15B03 under osx. If i run the same code unter Ubuntu 12.10, everything works fine.

I use the following options, when i open the socket :

```
-define(MULTICAST_GROUP, {239,255,255,250}).
-define(MULTICAST_PORT, 1900).
-define(OPTIONS,  [list,  {active,true}, {ip, ?MULTICAST_GROUP},{multicast_ttl, 255},   {reuseaddr,true},{multicast_loop,true}]).
{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(?MULTICAST_PORT, ?OPTIONS), 
inet:setopts(Socket ,[{add_membership,{?MULTICAST_GROUP, {0,0,0,0}}}]),
```

When i run the code under  OSX 10.7.5 i get the following error :

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Feb-2013::09:21:38 ===
** Generic server sender terminating 
** Last message in was send_alive
** When Server state == {state,#Port<0.929>}
** Reason for termination == 
** {{badmatch,{error,eaddrnotavail}},
[{sender,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/sender.erl"},{line,110}]},
{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]},
 {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
1...Address : {239,255,255,250}  Port : 1900
```

As i wrote before, the code same code runs under Ubuntu without errors.

Is there anybody out there who can help me?

Thanks,
Ulf

Comment: The error says that it can't find an interface. What does ifconfig -a tell you on the shell

Comment: Hi, i added {ip, local ip } and the error is gone. Now i am able to send messages, but i am not able to receive any message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i found my problems.

1. i had to add {ip, real ip} and not {0,0,0,0}
2. i have to send over my local ip.